How to show product categories in WhatsApp catalog using facebook commerce manager
I am building a e-commerce platform in WhatsApp using WhatsApp Business API. I created and connected the catalog using Facebook commerce manager. But I was not able to display the categorized collection of my products. It is displaying in WhatsApp catalog like a whole list. I need to categorize it.
I tried creating sets/collections in commerce manager but couldn't find a way to reflect them in WhatsApp catalog.
